# Azure inherited permissions

Tags: azure

I need that on all objects that are created in a "resource group", an "AD group" has contributor permissions

I dont want to give contributor access to the Resource Group.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right.  What you need to happen when you create a resource within a resource group is that a preset Contributor group is added to that resource automatically correct?  If this is the case then, you can achieve this by adding the preset Contributor group to your Subscription.  Then any resource group that derives from that Subscription will inherit the preset Contributor group.

Comment: no, sorry. Perhaps I didnt explain correctly. I want a user to have contributor access for all resources in a RG but not on the RG. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible the easy way by using the built in permission inheritance framework in azure.  The hard way would be that you would have to add the user to all the resources under the RG individually.